# Objective-C => Can't update existing objects in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I can't update objects in my database using core data, this my function :

```
- (void) saveItem:(NSDictionary*)dico {

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" 
        inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    Item *item =(Item *)[entity ReadSingleForKey:@"identifier"
                                           value:[dico valueForKey:@"identifier"]
                                       inContext:managedObjectContext];
    if (!item) {
        item = [[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] autorelease];
        item.identifier = [dico valueForKey:@"identifier"];
    }
    item.title = [dico valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No error found.");
    }
}
```

Even if "item" is not nil the object in the database doesn't change & I got always "No error found.".

```
- (NSManagedObject *) ReadSingleForKey:(NSString *) key 
        value:(id) value inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) context{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:self];

    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, value]];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *arr = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (arr && [arr count]) {
        return [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Any idea ??

Comment: How about actually putting in some error handling and maybe getting some useful error message to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my Item class :

I was using `@synthesize` instead of `@dynamic`

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code that make it difficult to determine the error.

1) No error handling.
2) Obscure private method `ReadSingleForKey` - what does it return?
3) `item` defined as type `Item` and as different type `NSManagedObject` in same method.

Put in `NSLog` statements or breakpoints to examine the values of `dico` and `item`. You will soon find the place where you go wrong.

Another potential source of this error is how you read the data from the database later. For now I am assuming that this is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my Question is updated can you review it please.

Comment: OK, now you can narrow it down. In `saveItem`, log your `dico` as well as the retrieved `item`, see if and how they are different. Maybe check that same value of `item` also in the `ReadSingleForKey` method. Then, the only thing you are changing is the `title` attribute. Now check the db (with `sqlite3`) and see if title has changed.